# Checked in Gridview, Button Click for Assign Value to textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, buttonclick

I try to complete the action for Button click to achieve checked row in gridview,  below is my asp.net code

If i click the Edit button , i want to assign gridview row ,column values into their textboxes .. how is it possible explain with code`

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    &nbsp;</div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="505px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView_SelectedIndexChanged" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"  />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    &nbsp;
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    </asp:GridView>
    &nbsp;<br />
    <br />
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<br />
    <br />
    &nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</form>
```

c#

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data source =;Database = ;Integrated security =true");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Empdetails", con);
        con.Open();

    GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Dispose();
    con.Close();



}
protected void GridView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if ((row.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox).Checked)
            {
                TextBox1.Text = row.Cells[0].Text;
                TextBox2.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
                TextBox3.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here using Empid is primary and 2 other columns .. but its doesn't execute correctly

Comment: where is Your btnEdit Button

Comment: thank you for ur reply Grant Winney, may i know y its doesnt work

Comment: Hi Ganesh Ty for ur reply Ganesh_Devlekar its on the code ,i edited now see

Comment: @BAP :what is the total number of columns in your GridView? what is the error you are getting? Which GridView are you talkin about here GridView or GridView1 (since in the asp code the you have GridView and in the code behind it says GridView1)?

Comment: Hi  user3240361, Its GridView only i edited now ..total no. of col. is 3..

Comment: Error 1 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.DataTable'                                         Error 2 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.DataTable' " these are the errors arise"               Error 3 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.DataTable' The name 'NewRow' does not exist in the current context     "this is the Error "

Answer (score 0):

Code behind. I'm creating a dataset to bind to the gridview and putting some dummy values in there. If you're not sure about how to bind data to a gridview, google it, theres plenty of examples! :)

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            var emps = new DataTable("Employee");
            emps.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() {ColumnName = "EmpId", DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32")});
            emps.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() {ColumnName = "Name", DataType = Type.GetType("System.String")});
            emps.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() {ColumnName = "Address", DataType = Type.GetType("System.String")});

            var dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataSet.Tables.Add(emps);

            var row = emps.NewRow();
            row["EmpId"] = 1000;
            row["Name"] = "John";
            row["Address"] = "1 Smith St";
            emps.Rows.Add(row);

            GridView1.DataSource = dataSet;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if ((row.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox).Checked)
            {
                TextBox1.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
                TextBox2.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
                TextBox3.Text = row.Cells[3].Text;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

This is the code for your aspx page

```
<div>
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Empid" Width="50px"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Name" Width="50px"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Address" Width="50px"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br /></div>   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="update " />  <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Edit" Width="61px" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
```

Comment: Error 1 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.DataTable' 
Error 2 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.DataTable'  " these  are the errors arise"
Error 3 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.DataTable' 
The name 'NewRow' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Ty  so much Garethb  ..again it shows the same error .. i amm trying to sort out .. if u knw pls let it know me

Comment: Sorry, I've misunderstood your question, I thought you were trying to add the textbox values to the gridview, but it looks like you want to add the gridview values to the textbox?

Comment: Yes thats perfect Garethb

Comment: can u help me to find the code .. i want basic notes wr i can able to learn tht

Comment: you are incorrectly referring to a datatable where you need to refer to the datarow. please correct it and edit your answer

Comment: @user3240361 - Thanks, was in a rush and missed that.

Comment: @BAP - Sorry, went on holiday and didn't have much internet access!

Comment: @garethb  hey no prob..  ty for ur reply here .. i could not  find out answer yet

Comment: I've misunderstood the question, so will delete my answer soon, but @user3240361 answer works for me?

Comment: Updated with the complete code including html, using @user3240361 answer for code behind

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this,may be the possible answer.

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
        CheckBox Ckbox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
        if (Ckbox.Checked == true)
             {
                 TextBox1.Text = row.Cells[1].Text; 
                 TextBox2.Text = row.Cells[2].Text; 
                 TextBox3.Text = row.Cells[3].Text; 
             }
        }
```

Comment: HI Shreyas Tg tHANK YOU FOR UR REOLY HERE ..iTS NOT EXECUTED

Comment: What exception you got?

Comment: Error 1 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.DataTable' Error 2 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.DataTable' " these are the errors arise" Error 3 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.DataTable' The name 'NewRow' does not exist in the current context "this is the Error " for the above code i edited now

Comment: @ShreyasTg: you are getting the cell index wrongly. It has to be 0,1,2 as he his girdView has only three cells in a Row.

Comment: Shreyas Tg nope its not execute

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to assign the GridView (named as GridView1) cell values of the row in which the CheckBox is selected to the three text boxes then below is the fix.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                if ((row.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox).Checked)
                {
                    TextBox1.Text = row.Cells[0].Text;
                    TextBox2.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
                    TextBox3.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
                }
            }
        }
```

and **most importantly please name the GridView in aspx as 'GridView1'** since u cannot have a class name for a ID

Comment: Nope its also doesn't .. i  want to add the gridview values to the textbox user3240361

Comment: then why did you change post to mean something different?

Comment: @ user3240361   : Yes am  try It not excecute

Comment: in that case you need comment on error or the issue you are facing now only then i will be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I want to Add the 'gridview row values' to the textbox ,so no answer for this Question ; share something  to read ,regading to this